# Checking which element is causing the event from a list of elements in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

I have a list of elements with its event listeners  like this :

```
var h1 = document.getElementById("h1"),
    h2 = document.getElementById("h2"),
    h3 = document.getElementById("h3");

var elemArray = [h1,h2,h3];

for(var i=0;i<elemArray.length;i++){
    elemArray[i].addEventListener("click",mouseListener,false);
}

function mouseListener(e){
    // code goes here
    // whenever it's called i want to know from
    // which element it's been called
}
```

Now what i want is whenever i click on one of the elements, 

I want to know which one has been clicked without using different functions for each element.

Comment: Define which one? Tag type? Content type? ID? Class?

Comment: The value of `this` in the event listener function will be a reference to the DOM element involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `this` variable inside your callback, it will point to the target element:

```
function mouseListener(e) {
    console.log( this.id );
}
```

Comment: To be accurate (since `e.target` could point to something else in the case of event bubbling), `this` points to the element that the event was registered with.

Answer (score 0):

```
function mouseListener(e){
     var elementEventWasSet = this;
     var clickedEl = e.target; // in case of bubbling, this is the one that was clicked
    // code goes here
    // whenever it's called i want to know from
    // which element it's been called
}
```

Comment: Rather unnecessary to declare something else as e.target when `this` exists. Not sure it was worthy of a downvote though, a comment yes.

Comment: @Popnoodles Who is using jQuery? The example puts them into variables to make clear what it's doing.

Comment: Don't understand why was it downvoted...The answer is "To the Point" I  believe..

Comment: @JuanMendes Hahahahah :D

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
function mouseListener(e){
    if(this === h1){
        console.log("First was pressed");
    }else if(this === h2){
        console.log("Second was pressed");
    }else if(this === h3){
        console.log("Third was pressed");
    }
}
```

This will work only if h1,h2 and h3 are global variable.
You can see this approach in action on this site:
http://jsfiddle.net/94xMu/2/